# SSD with Big Sur installed in it with an M1 MacBook air

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, apple-silicon

I have an SSD where I installed the OS with my Intel-based MacBook Pro 2017, so normally I log to this SSD "partition" where I have all my work Xcode... I'm asking if this same SSD would work the same way with an M1-based MacBook.

Comment: What do you mean with „log into“? Do you just use the SSD to store files?

Comment: Do you mean "Can I boot from an external disk on an M1 MBA?"..? Yes. As long as its an OS that supports the MBA, e.g. Big Sur or later.

Comment: Yes i mean can i boot from an external SSD on M1 MacBook air. The SSD was used with 2017 MacBook pro